# Error calling class's function using vector iterator c++

Tags: c++, vector

Let there be a class:

```
class lineCommand {
public:
    lineCommand(float startTime, float endTime);
    virtual ~lineCommand();

    //those are short inline functions:

    //setting the starting time of the command
    void setStartTime(const float num){mStartTime=num;};
    //setting the ending time of the command
    void setEndTime(const float num){mEndTime=num;};
    // returning the starting time of the command
    float getStartTime()  {return mStartTime;};
    // returning the ending time of the command
    float getEndTime() const {return mEndTime;};

private:
    float mStartTime;
    float mEndTime;
};
```

Then we create a vector of this class

```
std::vector<lineCommand> mAllCommands;
```

But when i try and work with iterator of that vector, Like that:

```
bool simulationTool::mSettingStartingTime(float startingTime){
    std::vector<lineCommand>::iterator tempIterator=mAllCommands.begin();
    while (tempIterator!=mAllCommands.end() && (*tempIterator).getStartTime()<startingTime){
        mActiveCommands.push_back(&(*tempIterator));
        tempIterator++;
    }
}
```

I get error in eclipse saying

```
invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘float’)
```

in the " (*tempIterator).getStartTime()

```
std::vector<lineCommand> mAllCommands;
    std::vector<lineCommand*> mActiveCommands;
```

Comment: The posted code looks OK to me. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JohnnyF Show how  mActiveCommands is declared.

Comment: What error do you get when you use `tempIterator->getStartTime()`?

Comment: Whey you say "I get error in eclipse saying...", do you mean you have compiled the code or is it just an error that eclipse is displaying before you compile? You may be able to compile the code without any errors although the eclipse editor does not like some parts of your code. My suggestion is to go ahead and compile the code and see if there are any real errors flagged by the compiler.

It is also better if you mark the method getStartTime() as const as its invocation does not modify the object.